# Deal with assumptions being made by accepted answers

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, bible, accepted-answer

I came across two approved answers, with a considerable number of upvotes/exposure, that seem to be assuming points as true, without them being properly discussed by the community, in light of the Bible.

• [Lesley](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/40418/lesley):

> There are definitely two types of angels mentioned in the Bible that
>   have wings - cherubim and seraphim  [[read full answer here]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/65768/34561)

• [Narnian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/207/narnian):

> The Bible actually does indicate that angels have wings, as both cherubim and seraphim are angels.  [[read full answer here]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4987/34561)

---

Given that, and my curiosity on the subject, I have decided to [ask a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/74878/34561) that will serve to understand the subject better, clarify those assumptions and test their validity.

However, for now, the question had only one answer and a few comments.

As this is an important subject, that may affect at least two other answers, how can we reach a canonical answer and get more users involved around the topic?

In the meantime, should I flag those answers and add a comment?

Comment: Your question was also provided with a link which you felt was TL;DR (too long, didn't read). The community can only do so much to help you. This is a huge topic requiring a lot of research. It is a topic that is greatly misunderstood. You are asking for considerable input on this question.

Comment: @Nigel-J I intend to analyze _your reflection_ on the topic (60,000 words) [that you shared in the comment section - I mentioned in this question that there were some comments apart from the answer], but as it requires a huge additional effort and I didn't have enough time (with all the responsibilities around me), I, politely, asked for a summarization. Indeed, the topic is misunderstood to the point that some users in this community have been using it lightly and doing lots of assumptions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may not intend this as your message, but your comment to Nigel comes off like  this: "I don't have the time but can someone else please spend the time?"  One of the nice  things about an SE site is that (1) you can answer your own question and (2) we don't need an answer "right now" - we can wait for a good or ever exceptional answer. What you can do is take the time, over the next week or so, and review Nigel's linked pdf ... and then summarize it in an answer. Self answering, when it is a good answer, certainly attracts up votes and appreciation by the other users.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Don't flag answers that are you think are wrong. Moderators aren't smart enough to figure out whether things are right or not.  We're exception handlers, only things that absolutely do not belong should be flagged.

What you can do for things that you feel aren't quite right is either.

1. Downvote and comments on answers you don't think are good enough.
2. Ask another question, but not a duplicate
3. If any other way you word another question would be a duplicate, then offer a bounty.

   There are a few stock reasons for offering the bounty that you may find appropriate if you try.  And once the bounty is offered, feel free to comment on the person who you think should improve their answer as to what you think is lacking.
4. Edit answers to improve details without changing the meaning of the answer.  It'll go into a review queue, but if you do it right, it may fix inaccuracies.  Few people attempt this, but it might work in your case

Comment: Just to contribute to a good response: difficult as it is, one has to allow others to draw their own conclusions and learn to differentiate between facts and supporting evidence towards the answer on the one hand, and personal opinion and beliefs on the other. Unfortunately, the expected format on this site does not seem to allow in-depth discussion of any arguments or interpretations brought forward.